# How can I obtain my public key (using web3)

Tags: web3js, private-key, signature, public-key

I know my Ethereum address, my Metamask wallet will give it to me, and I can run :

`web3.eth.coinbase`

But I want to know what my *public key* is.
Is there any way I can find that ?

(the reason I want to know a public key because I believe I need it to verify if a particular signed message was truely signed by that key)

Comment: If the message signature includes the _v_ value (in addition to _r_ and _s_)—which is the norm for signatures in Ethereum—then you can recover the public key, hash it to get the address, and see if the address matches. (You don't need to know the public key in advance.)

Comment: https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/02/17/signing-and-verifying-messages-in-ethereum/ may help.

Answer (score 2):

Using web3js it's not possible to fetch the public key of an account using its private key. Lots of people are getting confused between `address` and `public key` as both are different things.
But if you want to use any other 3rd party lib, you can use it via `ethereumjs-wallet`

Sample - https://piyopiyo.medium.com/how-to-get-ethereum-public-key-from-private-key-javascript-835c276e39bc

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while, but this should work
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#privatekeytoaccount

Comment: You can use recover to verify a signed message. But otherwise the public key is not exposed by web3.